# Tweenmax kill is not working if i declare yoyo true

Tags: jquery, gsap

I have tried to stop animation ,i have some repeated animation with the image,i have used yoyo true.it is not killing the function.how to get it done.

```
<script>
  var imgAnimation;
  imgAnimation=TweenMax.to(".img", 2, {
             top: '330px',
             repeat: -1,
             yoyo: true,
     });

 $("#imganim").click(function(){
     imgAnimation.kill();
 });

</script>
<button id="imganim">click to stop animation</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of your code working and the animation stops when you click the button to kill().

Working example: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/pjuan

My example uses the latest version of GSAP at the time of this writing 2.2.2

Make sure you are using the latest version of GSAP .. from CDN

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

To grab latest CDN link go to https://greensock.com/gsap and then click the **Download** button link in the nav.

Hope this helps! :)